# Windows 10 1803 - connecting ftp/http folder to Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I've a problem with mapping http website into explorer. When I try to do so, there is an error. It worked well in windows 7:)

Error from last screen: The enterer folder is incorrect....

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it works over HTTP like your expecting since the response would just be a web page that explorer wouldn't know how to parse for files.

Fortunately that url is also accessible via FTP instead:
ftp://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/

You can use the FTP url to successfully add the location.